# Converting a Vector Equation into a Scalar Equation where the Direction Vector is $(1,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've been working on some textbook problems, where I've had to convert vector equations into scalar equations. I've understood it for the most part, by converting the vector equation into parametric form, and then isolating for the parameter, and then equating them so i have an equation just in terms of x and y.

But, i was stuck on this question,

$[x, y]=[3, -8] + t[1,0]$

As usual, i converted it to parametric form giving me that

$x=3+t$ and $y=-8$

But since $y=-8$ does't have a parameter t, i'm stuck. Thank you!

Comment: what you got is right. But, do you know, in general, what $[x(t),y(t)]$ represents?

Comment: x, and y Components of the vector, right

Comment: ok, but depending on $t$, what do you get?

Comment: A point on the vector

Comment: No, the answer is a **curve** (a path in the plane), and in your example is a **line** (which is also a curve).

Comment: you should try some plotting, for example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%5B+t%5E2%2B1%2Ct%5D

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: what is the equation of a line that is parallel to the x-axis?

Comment: Could I please be told why this was down-voted? Thanks.